# const x= await User.find({name:'Hello'}) , What does this constant x store?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was learning some basic CRUD operation in mongoose and then I came across this.
This is my model

```
const User = mongoose.model('User',{
name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
}
})
```

and I wanted to find and delete items, I tried the traditional way, first finding and then storing it into a variable and then deleting them.
And these were my step

```
const x= await User.find({name:'Hello'});
x.forEach(x=>{
    console.log(x)
    x.deleteOne({name:'Hello'});
    })
```

It does the work as expected. And my question is, when we initialize  `const x= await User.find({name:'Hello'});` what do we store inside `x`. Is it like some reference or value? Because I am not sure how `x.deleteOne({name:'Hello'});`  deletes an item from the db.

Comment: so, if you remove `await` it would actually store a `Promise` object. `await` keyword will make sure that the promise is resolved, and the resolved value is stored there.

You can check the value of x, by directly doing a `console.log(x)` before the forEach loop

Comment: Ahh ! So that's what it's